# Return - Method Chaining 

Tags: php, oop

I have this code:

```
$db->get()->query()
```

Now i want the `get` method's return to depend on:

```
$db->get()
return $db->query var;
```

but

```
$db->get()->query()
```

the `get()` method will return `$this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:
You can't change the return depending on whether you've chained the code (which is what it looks like you want to do) - however for this particular problem you can implement the too string method which will 'appear' to do the same thing :)

```
<?php
class DB {

  private $query = 'some query';

  public function get()
  {
    return $this;
  }

  public function query()
  {
    // do the query function
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
     return $this->query;
  }
}

$db = new DB;
echo $db->get(); //prints 'some query'
$db->get()->query(); // runs the query() method
```

Comment: Yes but `$db->get();`(no query() function) will return $this->query; :D

Comment: Thanks, now my answers is using __tostring():  
    class DB {  
    private $query = 'some query';  
    public function __tostring(){  
    return $this->query;  
    }
    public function get()  
    {  
    return $this;  
    }  
    public function query()  
    {  
    query .....  
    }  
    }  
    $db = new DB;  
    echo $db->get()->query(); //Return result from query;  
    echo $db->get() // Return toString

Comment: @Snoob, note the get() method is now pointless.. you could remove it

Comment: No. echo $db->get() -> will return $this object, but my way is return $this->query;

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking but

```
$db->get()->query()
```

is the same as :

```
$somevar = $db->get();
$somevar->query();
```

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't know the calling context, eg. $x = $db->get(); or $db->get()->query(); So it doesen't know what to return. Make another function or add a param, if you really have to use it like that.